# Hash symbol syntax in ruby not working

Tags: ruby

I tried using regular syntax to create a hash

```
Hash = { 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6}
```

But got an error message of dynamic constant assignment.

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: The dynamic constant assignment doesn't have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: If you really want symbols, you have to wrap them in quotes: `{ '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3}`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's to be expected. Symbol literals follow the naming convention for identifiers. They can't start with a digit.